# Difference between storing an address versus a contract instance?

Tags: interfaces, inheritance

What is the difference between storing an address of a contract and using a interface to interact with it, versus storing the type of the contract itself (i.e. IPriceFeed v. PriceFeed) within the contract? Is one more gas efficient than the other?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small gas difference but between `Interfaces / (ABI calling)` and `call` and it's honestly really small and isn't recommended unless you're in certain situations.

Using address.call() is a bit cheaper. However

Interfaces or using the ABI of the contract allows for bugs to be caught such as:

- Reverts reporting
- Checking of the data types
- Check if the destination function exists or not